# how to get a value from a Jcombobox array using a anonymous class

Tags: java, arrays, swing, actionlistener, anonymous-class

I have a array of Jradiobuttons.i am trying to have java anonymous class that implement ActionListener so when the user press on a radio button I can do something but since  this is an array i cant give the array index using a while loop so how to identify what Jradiobutton I am using.and I want to get the text of that radio button and save it in a another variable...How can I do this?

This is what so far I have done :

```
if(count!=0) {
   rs=pst.executeQuery();
   JRadioButton a []=new JRadioButton[count];                       
   jPanel3.setLayout(new GridLayout());
   int x=0;
   ButtonGroup bg=new ButtonGroup();

   while(rs.next()) {    
     a[x]=new JRadioButton(rs.getString("name"));
     bg.add(a[x]);
     jPanel3.add(a[x]); 
     a[x].setVisible(true);

     a[x].addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {      

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,a[x].getText()); //here i cant use this x...even though i make x global value of x always will be 6 becouse of while loop.

        }
     });                  
     x++;
   }                            
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand you correctly, You can set the name of radio button:

```
a[x]=new JRadioButton(rs.getString("name"));
a[x].setName(rs.getString("name"));
```

and in `ActionPerformed` you get the source of action:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

if( e.getSource() instanceof JRadioButton){

  String selectedRadioName = ((JRadioButton) e.getSource()).getName();

  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, selectedRadioName );

}
```

Comment: and also can you tell me what is this instanceof JRadioButton means

Comment: Since your ActionListener in implemented as anonymius class so you dont need it. It is to check/confirm and process if you have clicked an JRadioButton (i.e. source of action is radio button) so that you shouldnt get class cast exception on type casting.

Answer (score 0):

## You could...

Supply each `JRadioButton` with a `ActionCommand` which will be made available via the `ActionEvent`

```
a[x]=new JRadioButton(rs.getString("name"));
a[x].setActionCommand(String.valueOf(x));
//...
a[x].addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            String cmd = e.getActionCommand();
            int value = Integer.parseInt(cmd);

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, a[value].getText());
        }
});
```

See [How to Use Buttons, Check Boxes, and Radio Buttons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html) for more details

## You could...

Use the `Action` API to surround the message and action in a self contained unit of work...

```
public class MessageAction extends AbstractAction {

    private String message;

    public MessageAction(String text, String message) {
        this.message = message;
        putValue(NAME, text);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, message);
    }

}
```

And then apply it to your button something like...

```
a[x] = new JRadioButton(new MessageAction(rs.getString("name"), "Hello from " + x);
```

See [How to Use Actions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html) for more details.